# Highlighting selected tab in nav - laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below in my view, but when i route to the page, the tab isn't showing as active. I search for this on answer on SO but it wouldn't solve my problem..

What am i not doing right?

I am using laravel version 5.6

**VIew**

```
<ul id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">         
          <li class="nav-item {{ Request::path() ==  '/admin/dashboard/foods/all' ? 'active' : ''  }}"><a href="/admin/dashboard/foods/all"  class="nav-link">
        <img src="/images/menubar/items.png" width="30px" height="30px" border="0" alt="Module Icon"/>
        <span>Food Items</span></a>           
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You've got the right idea; add a class based on the current route, but `Request::path()` might not be returning what you're expecting. I use `request()->is() ..`, so in your case `{{ request()->is("admin/dashboard/foods/all") ? "active" : "" }}`. Also try to debug `Request::path()` and see what it is.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis, that worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Request::path()` is returning, but it doesn't match your check for `/admin/dashboard/foods/all` (honestly, likely an issue with leading `/`)

Also, there is a method called `is()` on the `request()` helper that determines if the current route matches a given value, so use as:

```
<li class="nav-item {{ request()->is('admin/dashboard/foods/all') ? 'active' : ''  }}"> ...
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 3):

First i recommend you to put the logic in a directive, so the html look creaner and the logic is separated from the view.

In your AppServiceProvider you just put this

```
Blade::directive('menuActive',function($expression) {
    //explode the '$expression' string to the varibles needed
    list($route, $class) = explode(', ', $expression);
            //then we check if the route is the same as the one we are passing.
            return "{{ request()->is({$route}) ? {$class} : '' }}";
        });
```

know in your view you just add

```
<ul id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">         
      <li class="nav-item @menuActive('admin/dashboard/foods/all', 'active')"><a href="/admin/dashboard/foods/all"  class="nav-link">
    <img src="/images/menubar/items.png" width="30px" height="30px" border="0" alt="Module Icon"/>
    <span>Food Items</span></a>           
    </li>
```

Comment: That's pretty slick; always wondered how you added custom directives.